# focusout becomes undefined in another input

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

so my task is about to finish but I have a problem when I want to get the value of my two inputs. when I fill in email input I get the value, when move to find_us input the value from email input becomes empty.

here's my hierarchy html:

```
<div class="sm:mt-8">
        <div class="wa-button sm:mt-8">
          <label for="dialog-find">Email</label>
          <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Type your email" value autocomplete="off" class="input-lg">
        </div>
        <div class="wa-button sm:mt-8">
          <label for="dialog-find">How Did You Find Us? (Google, Facebook, Referral, Events, etc)</label>
          <input type="text" name="find_us" placeholder="Type your find us" value autocomplete="off" class="input-lg">
        </div>
        <div class="post-script text-center">
          <a target="_blank" class="button" id="button-wa" rel="noopener noreferrer">Contact Us</a>
        </div>
</div>
```

my javascript code:

```
// wa-button
// greetings is my global variable
        $('.form-group.wa-button').find('input').each( function(){

          const thes = this;
          // check attribute by name
          const attrName = $(thes).attr('name');

          $(thes).focusout(function(){
            let a;
            let b;
            if(attrName === 'email' ){
              a = $(this).val();
            }

            if( $(this).val().length >= 5 && attrName === 'find_us'  ){
              b = $(this).val();
            }

            // i want get those values from email and find_us
            $('#button-wa').attr('href', `${greetings} my email is ${a} and find from ${b}`)
          })

          
        }); //end selector
```

I've been looking for this solution several hours but couldn't find it. please help and tell me where i went wrong

thanks

Comment: Your current code does not work, because you only collect the input from _one_ input element at a time (`a` or `b`) leaving the other one `undefined`. The variable `thes` points to the _one_ input you just left (`focusout()`).

Comment: ohh i see.. but i thought thes in my code refer to one from the other.. because each.. repeats 1 selector (name="email") to the next selector (name="find_us"). Is it wrong? because that's what I was thinking from yesterday

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were making life unnecessarily complicated for yourself. Try the following instead:

```js
const greetings="hello";
$('.wa-button').on("input","input",function() {
  const a=$("input[name=email").val(), b=$("input[name=find_us").val();
  // I want get those values from email and find_us
  $('#button-wa').attr('href', `${greetings} my email is ${a} and I found you on ${b}`)
                 .each(function(){$(this).text('Contact us: '+$(this).attr("href"))});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="sm:mt-8">
  <div class="wa-button sm:mt-8">
    <label for="dialog-find">Email</label>
    <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Type your email" value autocomplete="off" class="input-lg">
  </div>
  <div class="wa-button sm:mt-8">
    <label for="dialog-find">How Did You Find Us? (Google, Facebook, Referral, Events, etc)</label>
    <input type="text" name="find_us" placeholder="Type your find us" value autocomplete="off" class="input-lg">
  </div>
  <div class="post-script text-center">
    <a target="_blank" class="button" id="button-wa" rel="noopener noreferrer">Contact Us</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

The `input` event will trigger each time something in the targeted input elements was entered, changed or removed. I used a delegated event attachment in

```
$('.wa-button').on("input","input",function()
```

**In reply to OP's question in the comments section:**

Collecting the variable values one after the other did not work in your code, because the variables were declared within their local context and became `undefined` as soon as the event function had finished its execution. If you want the variables to "survive" you need to define them in the global context (`var 1,b;`) but even then will their contents not always be reliable! The `.each()` will be looped only once, when we attach the event handler to *each* input element. The click itself will only cause *one* value to be read at a time! You can try it out in the snippet below.

```js
// The following is an example of how NOT TO DO IT!
// ================================================
// It is a slight modification of OP's original code
//
const greetings ="Hello"; // global variable
var a,b;

$('.wa-button').find('input').each(function() {

  const thes = this;
  // check attribute by name
  const attrName = $(thes).attr('name');

  $(thes).focusout(function() {

    if (attrName === 'email') {
      a = $(this).val();
    }

    if ($(this).val().length >= 5 && attrName === 'find_us') {
      b = $(this).val();
    }

    // i want get those values from email and find_us
    $('#button-wa').attr('href', `${greetings} my email is ${a} and find from ${b}`)
  })


});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="sm:mt-8">
  <div class="wa-button sm:mt-8">
    <label for="dialog-find">Email</label>
    <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Type your email" value autocomplete="off" class="input-lg">
  </div>
  <div class="wa-button sm:mt-8">
    <label for="dialog-find">How Did You Find Us? (Google, Facebook, Referral, Events, etc)</label>
    <input type="text" name="find_us" placeholder="Type your find us" value autocomplete="off" class="input-lg">
  </div>
  <div class="post-script text-center">
    <a target="_blank" class="button" id="button-wa" rel="noopener noreferrer">Contact Us</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: sir.. i wanna askk.. this code is works!!! many thanks.. but i still curious, why my code isnt work? i thought it was a good logic.. please explain me